# Can we get the per-tag questions count when viewing a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Once upon a time, there used to be list of tags and the amount of questions per tag in a question page. It was located in the right sidebar, and for me was something "nice to have", quick way to know how popular a tag is without having to click it.

Now that the Hot Network Questions took over, we don't have it anymore and no other way (except clicking a tag) to see how many questions are asked in a specific tag.

Can we have the ability back? If not in the same place, maybe in the tag popup?

> [image]

Why it will be useful, not just nice to have? Suppose you land on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459346/meteorjs-list-in-html-is-wigging-out). The [meteorjs](/questions/tagged/meteorjs) tag appears to be legit but if we could easily see it got only 2 questions it would be easier to understand the OP probably meant to use the existing [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor) tag instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm glad to announce that for some time now (at least a week) this is implemented in the tag "card":

> [image]

Comment: Blue free-hand circle? You've got to be kidding me...

Comment: @hichris123 red is used to mark what's wrong, at least for me, so blue looked like a proper choice to mark what's right. ;)